# How to iterate through >values< of a field in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
 ,id_number,x,y
0,000002,20,30
0,000002,30,30
0,000002,20,25
0,000002,10,3
1,000003,30,40
1,000003,40,50
1,000003,60,70
1,000003,70,78
....
```

As you can see there are several rows per each `id_number`.

What I want to do is to iterate first through all `id_number` or in pseudocode

```
for all id_numbers
   operate on the rows that have that id_number
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Use `groupby` with custom function.

Comment: @jezrael I did and it seems to work. The only thing is that `groupby` orders the output, therefore not respecting the order the rows appear in the original dataframe. Not a big deal but still...

Comment: use `df.groupby('id_number', sort=False)`